# Creating class schedule table in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a table to store users' class schedules. These schedules have 7 blocks a day for Monday through Friday. However, not all blocks are filled with classes.

I was planning on creating a table that stored stored a user's id, the period id, the class name, and the class subject in each record. If I implement it this way, what is the best way to determine when a user does not have classes using PHP? Is there a better layout for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make three tables, and set up a many-to-many relationship.

But if you don't want to get real complex, why not just insert the students free time like a class, call it 'free time', then you can just search for those.

SELECT * FROM records WHERE student_id = '0001' AND class = 'free time'

Otherwise, I'm not sure how you'd find an empty block without having a table devoted to the blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have another table that defines the blocks.

Comment: This is a tutorial I found to be helpful.  http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html

Comment: +1 for free time as a class, because then you can run calculations on it (total, avg, etc) which you cannot if you omit it like the other answer proposes

Comment: @Andrew Heath huh?  you can run any aggregate you'd like on the query i put.  free time as a class can be a big insertion anamoly.  you have to initialize every student with 7*5=35 free times and then update them instead of insert.

Comment: @jon - in all the schools I ever attended, free time had all the same characteristics as a class - start times, ending times, sometimes even teachers (proctors) - so it seems logical to me to handle them as items just like classes

Comment: So if you had 5 classes in the above scheme, you would have 30 documented free-time periods?  Is it possible we have a disconnect here bc I am thinking of scheduling in college terms and yours reflects high school?

Answer (score 3):

i wouldnt say you NEED to do anything, but i think you'll eventually find normalizing is a very good idea here.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

you probably want tables for:

```
student (id, name, whatever) 
course (id, name, subject/dept)
section (id, course id and time info) 
student_to_section (student id, section id)
```

Time depends.  You can put start/end times on sections (SQL timestamps or integer unix time stamps would each be fine) or keep a table of time slots with unique id (then sections would just have a foreign key to this id).  EDIT: sounds like you've chosen the second way

As for your free-time, find the time periods for all sections taken by a student and free time is whats left.   The following will give the time blocks where a student is BUSY.

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM section S 
INNER JOIN time_blocks T on S.time_id = T.id 
INNER JOIN student_to_section STS on STS.section_id = S.id 
WHERE STS.student_id = ###
```

For free time, use:

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM time_blocks T2
WHERE T2.id NOT IN
    (put above statement here)
```